# Firestore how to get last document of collection and add new with incremented id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have probably made a mistake with autogenerated id's for documents inside my events collection. I have added eventId for generated events and assigned eventId manually to each event.

Can I somehow get last document with its eventId and add new document with eventId of last document incremented by one.

Or should I delete autogenerated Id - based events and create new ones with non-autogenrated ids?

GitHub: https://github.com/Verthon/event-app

I have posted working React.js app on netlify: https://eventooo.netlify.com/

How it works:

- I added unique eventId to each dummy events inside of events collection,
- Based on that unique eventId I create link to specific single Event.js,
- User can create event providing information in /create-event,
- Once someone is creating an event I would like to add event to events collection with increment id, I have added 7 events created inside of console, so next should have id=7, something maybe like event1, event2 ... with autoincrement
- Inside of users collection I store currentUser.uid from auth and host name provided by user

```
Event Creator

submitEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const eventRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("events").doc();
    eventRef.set({
      title: this.state.title,
      host: this.state.host,
      localization: this.state.localization,
      description: this.state.description,
      category: this.state.category,
      day: this.state.day,
      hour: this.state.hour,
      featuredImage: this.state.imageUrl,
      uid: this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.uid
    });


    const citiesRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("cities").where("city", "==", this.state.localization);
    const cityRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("cities").doc();
    citiesRef.get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        if(querySnapshot.exists){
          console.log("exist");
          return
        }else{
          cityRef.set({
            city: this.state.localization,
          })
        }
      });
    const userRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("users").doc();
    userRef.set({
      user: this.state.host,
      uid: this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.uid
    });
```

[image: Firestore Settings]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want your `eventId` value to come from a number sequence. The best approach for such need is to use a distributed counter, as explained in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

I don't know which language you are using, but I paste below the JavaScript code of the three functions from this documentation and I write the code that will generate the sequential number that you can use to create the documents.

```
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  //From the Firebase documentation

  function createCounter(ref, num_shards) {
    var batch = db.batch();

    // Initialize the counter document
    batch.set(ref, { num_shards: num_shards });

    // Initialize each shard with count=0
    for (let i = 0; i < num_shards; i++) {
      let shardRef = ref.collection('shards').doc(i.toString());
      batch.set(shardRef, { count: 0 });
    }

    // Commit the write batch
    return batch.commit();
  }

  function incrementCounter(db, ref, num_shards) {
    // Select a shard of the counter at random
    const shard_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * num_shards).toString();
    const shard_ref = ref.collection('shards').doc(shard_id);

    // Update count
    return shard_ref.update(
      'count',
      firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    );
  }

  function getCount(ref) {
    // Sum the count of each shard in the subcollection
    return ref
      .collection('shards')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        let total_count = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          total_count += doc.data().count;
        });

        return total_count;
      });
  }

  //Your code

  var ref = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('counters')
    .doc('1');

  var num_shards = 2  //Adapt as required, read the doc

  //Initialize the counter bay calling ONCE the createCounter() method

  createCounter(ref, num_shards);

  //Then, when you want to create a new number and a new doc you do

  incrementCounter(db, ref, num_shards)
    .then(() => {
      return getCount(ref);
    })
    .then(count => {
      console.log(count);
      //Here you get the new number form the sequence
      //And you use it to create a doc
      db.collection("events").doc(count.toString()).set({
         category: "education",
         //.... 
      })
    });
```

Without much details on the Functional Requirements it is difficult to say if there is a difference between using the number form the sequence as the uid of the doc or as a field value in the document. It depends on the queries you may do on this collection.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited post with some explanation. It's complicated to me, because I'm working for the first time with database unfortunatelly.

Comment: I understand from your update that the main use of the eventId id is to "create link to specific single Event.js". So using the sequential eventId as document id is a good way.

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification. Still I don't know how to programmatically increment eventId when user submit another event. Should I loop through all events and somehow get and store the biggest eventId just to increment current one by 1? Sorry for trivial questions, but I'm stuck completely right now.

Comment: You could loop through all the events, but would need to use a Transaction to do so and only the Node.js API allows reading a set of documents in a Transaction. The client SDKs only offer the possibility to read **one document**. This is why my answer proposes a different approach: maintaining a counter that you increment each time you create a new document. The result is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added date to every document inside of events collection. To get last id I just query data with descending order with limit(1), after that I'm getting last id so I can increment it in new event added to collection. Next time I will definitely use your approach. Have a great day!

Comment: FYI the problem you may encounter with your approach is that between the time the user reads the events collection and writes the new document, another user does the same and create another "new" document, ending with two documents having the same userId. This is why, in this case, we normally use a Transaction (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), either when reading the collection  and creating the doc or when incrementing a counter.